# Keeping plane 1-sided while UVing

Tags: uv

I have added a pane.
I would now like to unwrap it and keep it 1-sided. 
I don't want to have any UV space on the back of the pane.
The pane will only be looked at from 1 way. Having UV space on its back would be a waste of ressources.

However, when I use Smart UV Project, Blender creates 2 sides for it: 1 for the back, and 1 for the font:

[image]

How could I avoid this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your properties panel, it looks like its a cube, not a plane. I can also tell because in your UV, there are more than 2 faces. There's actually 6.

To fix it, just edit your UVs. It won't take long at all. Or you can completely restart your UV job if you wish. I recommend doing so with one of the following methods.

**Regular Unwrapping**

Go into edit mode, sleect the faces you want to be in your UV, and hit <kbd>U</kbd> and then click on unwrap. You can edit the UVs further from the UV editor, as I am sure you are aware.

**Project From View**

If you don't already know how to project from view, I suggest [reading up on it](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/uv/unwrapping/mapping_types.html#project-from-view) as it is quite useful and I use it a lot. In your case, it should get the job done instantly.

Comment: Thank you very much! "Project from View" did the job! Also, I didn't notice I still worked with a cube. I was under the impression I had replaced it with a plane.